# How to install network settings on ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager

I have a vps running on ubuntu-18.04-x86_64 server

I'm a complete noob and I want to have a graphic interface, I've installed gnome desktop using "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop", and it works now, but I have no internet connection, and there are no settings where I can configure it or anything like that, is  there a way to fix it? or maybe a better way to install normal version on the server version?

Comment: I *suspect* it's a matter of editing your netplan settings to use the `network-manager` renderer - see for example [netplan vs NetworkManager on Ubuntu 18.04 and above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122757/netplan-vs-networkmanager-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-above). It might be helpful to [edit] your question to include the contents of your current netplan configuration (.yaml) file(s).

Comment: @luzijase If you find GNOME to consuming too much system resources, you can use XFCE or LXQt as a Desktop Environment for a GUI instead.